# Reading wav files in linux using .netcore 3.1

Tags: linux, .net-core, cross-platform, wav, naudio

I am developing an application in .netcore 3.1 which uses naudio to read wav files and checks if wav file has any sound or not. it works fine in windows but doesn't work in linux(centos-7). it throws error

> Unable to load shared library 'Msacm32.dll' or one of its dependencies

and then i found nAudio does not work in Linux: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/472

Can anyone please suggest any solution for this? Maybe any other library which can be used and works for linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did worked around for this by calling a python script from .net core. I used scipy.io.wavfile library to read wav file in pyhton. May be it will help someone.

Comment: I too encountered this and had to implement a similar work around (sigh*)